# Lucky Numbers Program not showing right answer

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a lucky numbers program using normal arrays so that the rest of the numbers in the list doesn't move forward. The pattern I'm following is 1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21, 25, 31, 33, 37, 43, 49, 51, 63, 67, 69, 73, 75, 79, 87, 93, 99,... For more info: [Lucky Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number)

Here's the program I've made:

```
public class LuckyNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] lucky = new int[101];

    for (int a = 0; a < lucky.length; a++){
        lucky[a] = a;
    }
    //goes through each element in list
    for (int b = 2; b < lucky.length; b++){
        //checks if number is surviving
        if (lucky[b] != 0){
            /*  if it does survive, go through the list deleting elements
             *  (setting them to zero) that fall on the 
             *  index of the multiples of the the surviving number*/
            int luckyNum = lucky[b]; // so that the number doesn't change
            for (int c = 1; c < lucky.length;c++){
                int d = luckyNum * c;
                if (d < lucky.length){
                    lucky[d] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int f = 0; f < lucky.length; f++){
        if (lucky[f] != 0){
            System.out.println(lucky[f]);
        }
    }
}   
}
```

The output is 1. I think it is a logic error.

Comment: Is the complete output just "1" or multiple "1"s ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You can see when exactly each number is eliminated. There're several problems with your logic. The program flow and output is not, in any way, surprising. Thus, I'm afraid, your question is unsuitable to Stackoverflow.

Comment: ISC practicals...right Apoorva ?

Comment: no im just 13 years old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this part of your code:

```
for (int c = 1; c < lucky.length;c++){
   int d = luckyNum * c;
   if (d < lucky.length){
     lucky[d] = 0;
     continue;
   }
}
```

When you take a look at wiki page, you have to remove every c-th surviving number. You're eliminating every multiple. So for number 3, you should eliminate `5, 11, 17 ...` not `3, 6, 9...` what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 17 to 23 do not eliminate the Nth remaining numbers.  You are assuming the remaining numbers are consecutive in the lucky number array, which they are not.  You will have to scan for / track the Nth remaining numbers to remove them.  It requires more logic, or find another data structure that makes this task easier to manage.

Comment: i could not understand properly

Answer (score 0):

Here, take my code for lucky numbers that I did for my school practical project :-

```
import java.io.*;
class LuckyNumbers
{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter the Number of Elements : ");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int a[]=new int[n];
    int c=n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i+1;
    }

    int del=1;
    System.out.println("\nLucky Number Operation :\n");

    while(del<n)
    {
        for(int i=del; i<n; i+=del)
        {
            for(int j=i; j<n-1; j++)
            {
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
            n--;
        }
        del++;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } //end of while

    System.out.print("\nHence, the Lucky Numbers Less than "+c+" are : ");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+"   ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the pattern i want